# Rewriting ASCII-percent-encoded locations to their UTF-8 encoded equivalent

Tags: nginx, rewrite, utf-8

For example, “å” can be encoded as /%E5 and /%C3%A5 (utf-8). All my filenames are UTF-8, so the ASCII variants return a 404. I want both variants to work.

I have tried rewriting the incorrect URLs to the correct encodings with variations of the below configuration. I have not been able to actually match the locations so have not gotten anywhere.

```
rewrite ^/%E5$ /%C3%A permanent;
rewrite ^/%25E5$ /%25C3%25A permanent;
location = /%E5 { return 301 /%C3%A; }
```

How am I supposed match these percent encoded locations?

Comment: @MichaelHampton in UTF-8 bytes `0xC3 0xA5` is exactly Unicode `U+00E5`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [here](https://serverfault.com/q/648308/72586) for the same issue in Apache - there, I recommended using an external program to handle the rewrite, since it's clunky to do it in native configuration.

For nginx, the best approach might be to embed some perl in your configuration via `ngx_http_perl_module` - use `perl_set` to set a variable to a UTF-8-ified version of `$r->uri`, using the `Encoding` module (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10377165/converting-a-string-to-utf8-with-perl)), and rewrite (or probably better, `try_files`) to that.

**Edit:**

If you want to just do this by hand for specific URLs or specific characters, then you're just missing a couple things in your attempts:

- You're working against escaped URLs, while the rewrite should be happening against the string after decoding escaped characters
- You're hardcoding the matches to be for files that are *just* the special character, not files that *contain* the special character

Try something like this..

```
rewrite (*UTF8)^(.*)\xe5(.*)$ %1å%2;
```

Comment: Can I achieve this on a smaller scale for one or two URLs? Seems like a over engineered solution for just one–two addresses.

Comment: @Aeyoun Your question is certainly worded like you want a general solution, not just for specific addresses.  Edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks for broadening the answer. `rewrite (*UTF8)^(.*)\xe5(.*)$ /elsewhere;` triggers a 500 response.

Comment: @Aeyoun What's logged for the 500 response?  What about if you make it a redirecting rewrite with `permanent`?

Comment: I needed to `apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev` first. All my other regexes worked, so I did not suspect that was the problem. After doing that, almost all my previous attempts also started working.

Comment: extra callout for the *why* of `\x`: `\x` is the regex escape sequence, and thus the regex-equivalent of `%` in URLs.
(I think this deserves attention because [it stumped me in apache too](https://serverfault.com/q/1036007/303501) )