# Syntax for apache RewriteRule to match %-encoded URLs? (to fix character encoding issues; windows-1252 <=> utf-8 )

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, encoding, utf-8

I host a webpage that has  '`project²`' in the URL, matching an on-disk directory `project²` from where static files are hosted.

This page is used by a java-based client to load data from URLs (bioinformatics software [IGV](https://software.broadinstitute.org/software/igv/)).
My page lists URLs in the form of `http://localhost:60151/load?file=http://example.org/project²/some/data/file.bam`.
Clicking these links in the browser will cause the IGV client (running on localhost) to request `GET http://example.org/project²/some/data/file.bam` from my server.

✅ IGV on Linux/Mac responds by requesting this URL as UTF-8 encoded `²`=`%C2%B2`, and everything is happily working.
❌ My newly gained Win-10 user's client requests `²`=`%B2` (windows-1252 encoded), resulting in a 404-not-found.

After trying dozens of things, I am at wits end how to help this user.

I have the impression that I should be able to dynamically rewrite the wrongly-encoded URLs on the server-side, so that they still end up serving the desired data, but **I do not know the magic character combinations to make the rule-patterns match escaped characters.**

---

#### Things I've already tried

- Doublechecking that the 404s are not network issues; I see the `GET %B2` in my `ssl_access_log` with `404` as the returned statuscode, so it really is the server doing it.
- 'Proper' way: UrlEncoding the URL before giving it into the client. Perl's `URI::Encode` `encode_uri` turns the `²` into `%C3%82%C2%B2` (apparently `Ã²`?) which is *even more wrong* somehow?
- triple-checked that the webpage providing the load-URLs is served as utf-8

  - it provides header `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`
  - Set `AddDefaultCharset UTF-8` in `httpd.conf`
  - It seems the encoding info is not transferred through from webbrowser API-link-click into the Java program
- 'doubled' the directory by symlinking <s>`projectª -> project²`</s> and `project%B2 -> project²` <s>(`ª` is the UTF8-match for `%B2`)</s> *edit: ª is in no way related; no idea where I got that from*
- Tried to `mod_rewrite` 'bad' URLs into good ones in several different ways, none of which seem to catch:

```
RewriteEngine on
# RewriteRule Pattern Substitution [flags]
RewriteRule (.*)project%B2/(.*) $1project²/$2 [NE] # encoded 'bad' request, unencoded redirect
RewriteRule (.*)²(.*) $1%C2%B2$2 [B,NE]            # config file is utf-8 encoded, so this is senseless.      
RewriteRule (.*)%B2(.*) $12$2 [B,NE]               # doesn't match?        
RewriteRule (.*)TZZT(.*) $1test$2                  # works, so RewriteEngine is working
```

The [RewriteRule](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) and [RewriteRuleFlags](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html) docs also do not help me understand how I should encode the `Pattern`-part so that it'll work :-(

---

**Similar questions on here**

- [Can Apache .htaccess convert the percent-encoding in encoded URIs from Win-1252 to UTF-8?](https://serverfault.com/questions/648308/can-apache-htaccess-convert-the-percent-encoding-in-encoded-uris-from-win-1252) -> an external encoding program `rewritemap` seems overkill, since it is literally only one folder `project²`, so my scope is smaller.
- [Rewriting ASCII-percent-encoded locations to their UTF-8 encoded equivalent](https://serverfault.com/questions/656096/rewriting-ascii-percent-encoded-locations-to-their-utf-8-encoded-equivalent) same problem in NGinX, point to the above Apache-question.

Comment: "`ª` is the UTF8-match for `%B2`" - How did you derive this? This does not appear to be correct (which is part of the problem). `ª` (U+00AA "[feminine ordinal indicator](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00aa/index.htm)", not strictly "superscript-a") as UTF-8 would URL encode as `%C2%AA`. `%B2` itself does not decode to anything printable in a UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: "ª": I found this in an online table that listed encoded values side by side for utf-8 and win-1252, and followed that in reverse direction. From what you describe, I massively misinterpreted that source, or the source is wrong.
I can't for the life of me recreate the search terms that lead me to it, so I'll have to check the browser history of my work-pc, which I can't do until next week (currently work-from-home). I'll get back to it; for now I've editted the question to make it clear it's probably wrong.

Comment: Finally at my work PC again; found the encoding source I used: [teixeira-soft url encoding reference](http://www.teixeira-soft.com/bluescreen/html-url-encoding-reference/) (has both windows-1252 and utf-8)
It doesn't support my reasoning, so that seems to have been a brain-fart of me, probably delusional after too long stuck in the debugging hole...
Question updated to reflect this and prevent confusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

**`RewriteRule`s must use `\x` instead of `%` in order to match %-encoded URLs!** (PCRE syntax for byte sequences)

`mod_rewrite`-config uses PCRE regex syntax, and operates on decoded URLs, so typing a `%`-encoding in a `RewriteRule` pattern causes it to look for the literal `%`-character, not an encoded value.
The correct escape-character in RewriteRules is `\x`, so the URLencoded value `%B2` can be matched using `\xb2` (or `\xB2`, it's case-insensitive).

**Note that `RewriteRule` is a hacky solution for character encoding issues**, that only works when there is exactly one specific wrong-encoded character is in a specific, predictable place.

For a general solution for multiple wrong-encoded characters in arbitrary places, please see [Can Apache .htaccess convert the percent-encoding in encoded URIs from Win-1252 to UTF-8?](https://serverfault.com/questions/648308/can-apache-htaccess-convert-the-percent-encoding-in-encoded-uris-from-win-1252) , which suggests a general solution using `RewriteMap` coupled to an external program in a full-featured programming language.

The *proper* solution is still to prevent this from the source, using explicit %-encoding throughout the entire chain. This avoids OS-dependent encoding accidentally happening 'somewhere in the middle', outside of your control.
(assuming no client along the paths does double-encoding, which should be a punishable offense..)

---

#### How I got here

Getting desperate, I upped the server-wide logging using `LogLevel Warn rewrite:trace3` as suggested in [mod_rewrite docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging). This is warned to (heavily) impact server performance, but was manageable because this is a low-traffic server, and there were no pre-existing rewrites.

The additional logging is emitted into (`ssl_`)`error_log`.
This gave me insight into how exactly the matching was attempted, and what the internal representations for rules and URIs are in `mod_rewrite`.

excerpt from `ssl_error_log` (many columns ommitted for brevity),
with rule `RewriteRule (.*)project%B2/(.*) $1project²/$2 [NE,L]`

```
[rewrite:trace3] applying pattern '(.*)project%B2/(.*)' to uri 'project\xb2/'
[rewrite:trace1] pass through /var/www/html/example.org/project\xb2
```

Note that the request-uri from client is written `\xb2`, but my pattern uses `%B2`.

Matching the rule-syntax to the uri-syntax, with rule `RewriteRule (.*)project\xB2/(.*) $1project²/$2 [NE,L]`

```
[rewrite:trace3] applying pattern '(.*)project\\xb2/(.*)' to uri 'project\xb2/'
[rewrite:trace2] rewrite 'project\xb2/' -> 'project%c2%b2/'
[rewrite:trace1] internal redirect with /auth-test/project\xc2\xb2/ [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
```

success!  As we can see, we are now matching!

---

#### Why no `[R]`/`[R=302]` flag?

As this is a character-encoding issue, I do not think doing an extra HTTP-round-trip will add value; Every link fed into the client will run into the same issue again, unless I fix the encoding issue *before* feeding it into the client-side java-program.

---

#### Don't forget `RewriteBase`

Please note that this shortened version omits setting the correct [`RewriteBase`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteBase), which can screw up the rewritten path, depending on where in your `conf` it is written (e.g. `<Directory>` vs `<Location>`). Without `RewriteBase` I accidentally redirected to ❌`https://example.org/var/www/html/rewrite-testing/project²`  instead of ✅`https://example.org/rewrite-testing/project²`)

Comment: `\x` is regex syntax (not particular to mod_rewrite) for representing any character using a hex code. So, `\xB2` matches the literal character that `%B2` (URL encoding) decodes to. Since the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ matches against the %-decoded URL-path. Just as the regex `\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f` matches the literal string "hello". `%B2` is a non-printable character when UTF-8 decoded, so can only be represented by the hex code in the regex.

Comment: My windows user has confirmed that "it works now" (yay), so I'm selfishly accepting my own answer.
@MrWhite; You've invested quite a lot of time into my question, and not even getting the covetted green-check, sorry!
I'm not sure what the proper etiquette is for thanking you, other than thanking you. (Upvote of your answer seems wrong somehow, since even though well-researched, it didn't apply due to my unclear phrasing; sorry!)

Comment: @MrWhite I Just realised you've massively updated your answer, you definitely deserve the upvote now!

Answer (score 3):

You can't "convert encodings" as such using only mod_rewrite, however, you can search for that specific sequence of characters in the requested URL and "correct it".

> ```
> http://localhost:60151/load?file=http://example.org/project²/some/data/file.bam
> ```

> ```
> RewriteRule (.*)project%B2/(.*) $1project²/$2 [NE]
> ```

Note that `project²` appears as part of the *query string* in the example URL you posted, however, the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (which you are using above) matches against the %-decoded URL-path only (which excludes the query string). To match against the query string you need to use an additional `RewriteCond` directive and match against the `QUERY_STRING` (or `THE_REQUEST`) server variable instead.

Note that the `QUERY_STRING` (and `THE_REQUEST`) server variable is %-encoded (or rather, as sent from the client) - they have not been %-decoded.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)/project%B2/(.*)
RewriteRule ^(load)$ $1?%1/project%C2%B2/%2 [NE,L]
```

The backreferences `%1` and `%2` in the *substitution* string refer to the preceding *CondPattern* - the parts before and after the troublesome `/project%B2/` part.

`$1` is simply a backreference to the URL-path (to save repetition), which I assume is always `load`.

The `NE` flag prevents the `%` itself (when used as part of the URL-encoded characters) being URL encoded.

> **UPDATE:** I'm afraid my original question was unclear about who GETs which URL, so the "query-string" part of your answer doesn't apply...

If you need to match the **%-encoded URL-path** then you should match against `THE-REQUEST` server variable instead. `THE_REQUEST` contains the first line of the HTTP request header and is not %-decoded. It contains the full URL-path (and query string) as sent from the client (as well as the request *method* and protocol version). For example, in the case of the malformed request, a string of the form:

```
GET /project%B2/some/data/file.bam HTTP/1.1
```

Which you could match and correct as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,7}\s(/project)%B2([^\s]+)
RewriteRule ^/?project %1%B2%C2%2 [NE,L]
```

`%1` and `%2` are backreferences to the captured subpatterns in the preceding *CondPattern*.

The `RewriteRule` *pattern*, on the other hand, matches against a pre-processed %-decoded URL-path only (as mentioned above). So, `%B2` is whatever that decodes to; assuming a UTF-8 encoding. Unfortunately, this is a non-printable character so would need to be represented by the hex character sequence in the regex, ie. `\xb2` (this is PCRE syntax representing a single byte sequence).

Comment: Thank you very much for thinking along!
I'm afraid my original question was unclear about who `GET`s which URL, so the "query-string" part of your answer doesn't apply :-( 
I've updated my question to make this (hopefully) more clear.

(What happens: Webpage has link to `localhost:60151/load?/load?file=example.org/foo`; clicking that will trigger IGV (listening on localhost) to do `GET example.org/foo` from my server, thereby taking the troublesome part 'back out' of the query-string)

Comment: Second point: The fact that RewriteRule operates on the 'raw'/non-decoded URL is highly valuable information, which was previously unclear to me. I'll try if this helps me further and report back.

Comment: I've updated my answer addressing the invalid char in the URL-path (as opposed to the query string). The solution is very similar - just using `THE_REQUEST` instead of `QUERY_STRING`.

Comment: "The fact that RewriteRule operates on the 'raw'/non-decoded URL is highly valuable information" - this is not true. (That's not what I stated above?) In fact, the opposite is true... the URL-path that the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ matches against is %-decoded and pre-processed. I've also addressed this in my answer.

Comment: Ah, seems I misunderstood "they have not been %-decoded"; great clarification.
And thank you for explaining _why_ `\x` works; It seems obvious looking back, but it didn't occur to me in this context, despite the fact I eat Regex for breakfast...
(so..many.. layers.. of processing, escaping, unescaping, and re-unescaping-for-printing.. argh!);

`%B2` decoded becomes a superscript-a, but when I wrote that into the rewrite-rule, it also didn't catch, even though it should be the same byte.

Comment: "`%B2` decoded becomes a superscript-a" - ah, but it doesn't. I'm curious how you derived that? (Maybe a mix of encodings?) I've left a longer comment on your question above.